# How to push your local master branch to Heroku when you've already pushed a feature branch?

Tags: git, heroku

To try out a feature branch, I pushed it to Heroku's master (since that's the only branch it uses for your website), i.e. I did:

```
git push heroku feature-foo:master
```

Meanwhile, I made some commits to my local master branch. Now I want to push my local master back out to Heroku, but am getting:

```
To git@heroku.com:foo-repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:foo-repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

This makes sense, because indeed Heroku's master is really on my feature-foo branch and thus is ahead of master. But I don't want to pull and merge from Heroku -- because that would be the same as merging my feature-foo branch, which I don't want to do. Right now, I just want to push my local master without the feature-foo commits. (Indeed I have already used `heroku rollback` so that the feature-foo changes aren't live on the site.)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer turns out to be simple. Do a forced push, i.e.

```
git push -f heroku master
```

Comment: Yes, as it turns out, git is not a particularly good tool for deployment. Deploying to heroku with git often involves doing things that you'd never want to do with a real git repo.

Comment: the issue you had is that somebody else published on master and your content is behind. This solution is going to override their work and cause more problems later.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to your sites heroku dashboard and rollback to a previous build from before you pushed off a non master branch.

visit `dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-goes-here/activity`

Once there you should see:

[image]
Click `Roll back to here` on the build you'd like to go back to. Once you've rolled back to correct build you can push from master without having to use force.